# Can we call function inside an function SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
ALTER function [dbo].[getEmployeeID](@ID int) returns table
as  
  begin
  return (
    select * from [dbo].[gtEmployeeName](2)
    select * from Employees where EmployeeID = @ID)
end
```

here `[dbo].[gtEmployeeName]` is an other function that I am trying to call.

I am getting an error,  can we call or is there any syntax problem?

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure getEmployeeID, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure getEmployeeID, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Thanks
Prince

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `[dbo].[gtEmployeeName]` returns scalar you probably are looking for

```
ALTER function [dbo].[getEmployeeID](@ID int) returns table
as  
begin
return (
    select *, [dbo].[gtEmployeeName](2) as EmpName from Employees where EmployeeID=@ID)
end
```

If `[dbo].[gtEmployeeName]` returns table you probably are looking for

```
ALTER function [dbo].[getEmployeeID](@ID int) returns table
as  
begin
return (
    select * from [dbo].[gtEmployeeName](2) EN
    inner join Employees E on EN.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    where EmployeeID=@ID)
end
```

Update the join to outer if that is what you need. Also update the `join condition` (the example assumes that the returned table from `gtEmployeeName` has a column `EmployeeID` and that can be used for joining to Employees.

Comment: I'd also suggest investigating why the parameter to gtEmployeeName (2) is hard-coded. What does this value represent (I suspect EmployeeID but there's not enough peripheral information)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can call a function inside a function.

In fact, you can call the current function inside the function, to cause a loop.

What error are you getting? Your error is most likely related to something else